# "Extra argument in call" for a function inside ViewController

Tags: swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func raise(base: Int, exp: Int) -> Int {
        if (exp == 0) {
            return 1
        }
        else {
            return base * raise(base, exp: exp - 1)
        }
    }

    var check = raise(2, exp: 4)  // error here

    print(check)

}
```

I am very new to coding and learning about recursion. I simply wanted to call the function `raise` to see how it would work, but I get this error:

> extra argument in call

Could someone tell me why I am getting this error? Thank you.

Comment: I am using Swift 2.0 and it doesnot give any error to me when I used your code.

Comment: In an older version of Swift, the call would be `var check = raise(2, 4)`.

Comment: @Nishant it is ok because you use playground? Try in project.

Comment: @wm.p1us: I used it in project only. Please check Philip's comment that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `var check = raise(2, exp: 4)` is at the root level of your class, you can't do that. You have to put this call in a function or outside the class. Here we call from inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func raise(base: Int, exp: Int) -> Int {
        if (exp == 0) {
            return 1
        }
        else {
            return base * raise(base, exp: exp - 1)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var check = raise(2, exp: 4)

        print(check)
    }

}
```

And in Swift 1, you wouldn't *have* to specify the name of the second parameter if it wasn't marked with `#` in the function signature, there was a distinction between functions and methods. This isn't the case anymore with Swift 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call function inside the implementation of the class. if you try to change your code like this it will work well (as recursion)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

func raise(base: Int, exp: Int) -> Int {
    if (exp == 0) {

        let check = raise(2, exp: 4)  // no error here  
        print(check)
        return 1
    } else {

      let check = raise(2, exp: 4)  // no error here
      print(check)
      return base * raise(base, exp: exp - 1)
    }
  }
}
```

And be sure that you write code BEFORE you return anything otherwise it will not run.